# Return the node itself using recursive DFS in C

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I would like to write a recursion that searches a tree, looking for a node that has an appropriate piece of data, and then returns the node itself. I need the node itself because I will then use that node to continue to build the tree. I have tried many versions of this function, but the below code is the closest I have come. Please note that I am representing a general tree as a binary tree as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-child-right-sibling-representation-tree/), so I think that for all intents and purposes this can be treated as a binary tree.

```
struct node {
     int id;
     struct node *firstChild;
     struct node *nextSibling;
};

struct node* findNode(struct node* node, int id) {
     if (node->id == id) 
          return node;

     if (node->firstChild != NULL)
          return findNode(node->firstChild, id);

     if (node->nextSibling != NULL)
          return findNode(node->nextSibling, id);

     return node;
}
```

I understand the issue with this code: if a left (child) branch exists and the desired node is not in that branch, then it returns the leaf of that branch rather than exploring the right branch. I know that my code has way too many return statements; I have tried other versions with fewer returns but haven't found a function that works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say *"returns the node itself",* do you mean that it returns (a copy of) the node by value, or that it removes the node from the tree and returns it? Or that it returns a pointer to the node?

Comment: @Beta or they could mean that it returns the node and like... doesn't remove it from the tree because why would it. And the function appears to be designed so that it returns a pointer, not a copy.

Comment: Good question. I think I mean that it should return the node by value. I do not want the node to be removed from the tree; I want to build on the node. So I guess I am trying to find the location of the node in memory, so that I can build onto that.

Comment: **P.S.** Also, giving a *struct* and a *variable* the same name makes your code -- and any attempt to talk about it -- very cryptic. And giving a *pointer* a name that suggests a non-pointer... Use better names, dude.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with not knowing what "by value" means; there's something very wrong with not knowing what it means, thinking that you do, and using it. Sorry if I sound harsh, but you have a lot of bad habits to shed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I aspire to use better names; I'm afraid I just don't have enough experience. I can edit my post with better names if it will be helpful to you and others. What would you recommend?

Comment: So this is how I understand it:
Return by value / by copy would be returning a `struct node`. Return by pointer would be returning a `struct node*`. The latter allows you to access *the very node you found* and change data in the structure directly. In C++ there's also return by reference, which returns `struct node&` and works like return by pointer except the code looks like with return by value / copy, that is, there is no dereferencing. It's syntactic sugar. Admittedly, it might be a bit confusing, but you get the hang of it quickly.

Comment: @Maurycyt That makes sense. With those definitions in mind, I would like to return by pointer. More specifically: I want to add a child node to a given parent. I know the id of the parent, so I would like to search the tree for the parent and then create a new child on that parent. However, I cannot create the child directly because the parent may already have children. So I want to return the node "by pointer" (it sounds like) so that I can check if that node already has children.

Answer (score 1):

For starters there is a typo in the structure definition

```
struct node {
     int id;
     int node *firstChild;
     int node *nextSibling;
};
```

It seems you mean

```
struct node {
     int id;
     struct node *firstChild;
     struct node *nextSibling;
};
```

Your function does not check whether the current pointer to a node is equal to NULL.

The function can be defined the following way

```
struct node * findNode( struct node *node, int id ) 
{
    if ( node == NULL || node->id == id )
    {
        return node;
    }

    struct node *target = findNode( node->firstChild, id );

    if ( target == NULL )
    {
        target = findNode( node->nextSibling, id );
    }

    return target;
}
```

Though as in C there is no function overloading then the function should be declared and defined like

```
struct node * findNode( const struct node *node, int id ) 
{
    if ( node == NULL || node->id == id )
    {
        return ( struct node * )node;
    }

    struct node *target = findNode( node->firstChild, id );

    if ( target == NULL )
    {
        target = findNode( node->nextSibling, id );
    }

    return target;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the typo in my original question. FWIW, I have seen your answers elsewhere on this website, and thank you so much for taking the time to help me too!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract the results from both branches and compare them.

Try the following:

```cpp
struct node {
     int id;
     int node *firstChild;
     int node *nextSibling;
};

struct node* findNode(struct node* node, int id) {
     if (node->id == id) 
          return node;

     node *fC = findNode(node->firstChild, id);
     node *nS = findNode(node->nextSibling, id);

     //if the node is guaranteed to exist in the tree
     return (fC->id == id) ? fC : nS;

     //if the node is not guaranteed to exist in the tree
     if (fC != null && fC->id == id)
          return fC;
     if (nS != null && nS->id == id)
          return nS;
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the result of `findNode` in a variable (`target`).
Then check `target` if it's `NULL` which means it wasn't found and search in `nextSibling`.  Like this, `nextSibling` will only be searched if the node wasn't found in the `firstChild`.

```
struct node* findNode(struct node* node, int id) {
     if (node == NULL) return NULL;
     if (node->id == id) return node;
     
     struct node *target = NULL;
     if (node->firstChild != NULL)
          target = findNode(node->firstChild, id);

     if (target == NULL && node->nextSibling != NULL)
          target = findNode(node->nextSibling, id);

     return target;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have copied and pasted my solution?

Comment: I didn't, I went from the original code from the question. I only borrowed your variable name. The difference between our answers is that mine checks the two children of the node if they are NULL just like the asker did. Otherwise there could be segmentation faults.

Comment: It was my first version of the code in my answer that I then updated.

Comment: You could be right. I did look at your code before answering, so I probably subconsciously did the same thing as you. Sorry about that.